# Unexpected Shutdown

Tags: laptop, shutdown, battery, performance

Today and before have encountered unexpected shutdown. My laptop have a new battery, because the old one died, but this also happened to me with this.

I see that this happen to me when the system use 100% of the CPU using the turbo boost.

This are my specs:

[image]

I tried to use the `indicator-cpufreq` to set the system on battery saver but this gave a very bad performance and the conservative mode does not limit the maximum of the CPU.

Also this does not happen to me on Windows 10 but I saw that windows limit to 60% the performance when its on battery.

And it does not be overheating because I played video games recently on windows without problems.

What can i do to limit the performance or to not have that shutdowns? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing tlp it's a must have for laptop power management, the default settings are great but it is also very customisable.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```